# Swift Alamofire post request doesn't work,

Tags: json, swift, http, post, alamofire

I am trying to send simple http post request through Alamofire. I need username and password, and the body of the request is in json format.
first I am not sure if my code is correct or not(beginner in Apple develeper.)
secondly, I am confused everytime I excited the code, it did not go to the responseJSON block at all. can somebody give me a hint, thank you 
here is my code

```
func sendTestResult(result: Int, testrun: Int, testcaseindex: Int) -> Bool{
    var resp : Bool = false;

    //add testcase info
    var url: String = self.testrailsUrl + "/\(testrun)/\(testcaseindex)"
    //add authentication info
//        url = testrailsUrl + "/basic-auth/\(self.testrailsUserName)/\(self.testrailsPassword)"

    assert(url == "http://ypdine.testrail.net/index.php?/api/v2/add_result_for_case/4/3",
        "the post information isn't right")

    let parameters = ["status_id": [result]]
    print("here sending the request")
    Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
        .authenticate(user: self.testrailsUserName, password: self.testrailsPassword)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
        }

    return resp
}
```

Comment: Is it really not entering block, or is in entering and `response.result.value` just `nil`. Check `response.result.error`.

Comment: Hi @Rob thank you first for your attention,
it is really not entering the block , I set the break point and went step by step. it hit the .responseJSON line, and jump to return directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the '-> Bool' and the 'return resp' from your function to give Alamofire a chance to respond.